# journalctl timpestamp format

Tags: linux, timestamp, journalctl

##### `journalctl -S [timestamp]`

So journalctl prints out a lot of info, as those reading this probably already know. There is a flag `-S` (or `--since`) that allows the user to pinpoint the date of the logs she is looking for. I got some error message that is associated to the GNOME font viewer, and I wanted to check `journalctl` to see what it said, but there were so many log entries that scrolling through them all using <kbd>PG DOWN</kbd> would literally take me most of the day (I should probably clear my caches & logs more often). There is a flag that helps pinpoint a specified date of logs. If you know when the log you want to view to place, you can use this tool to keep from scrolling through a Googol-plex of logs.

My problem is that each time I have tried using the flag I received an error message that basically read (in not so many words), "the timestamp you are using is incorrect, fix it and try again." Typing `journalctl --help` doesn't not mention the format to use, neither does the error message which is very frustrating. Furthermore, when I say, "each time I used it", I am referencing times that span over years. I just open up the log file manually by navigating to the system logs and use my editor to copy the file into a separate directory where I can delete what I don't need, and preform a regex search for what I want. I would like be able to just enter the timestamp in though, in theory, it should be much faster.

Can anyone give me a working example that demonstrates the should be used to enter the timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All formats are documented in the [systemd.time(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html) manual page, with examples included.

The easiest format is a *relative* timestamp: `-1h` for "1 hour ago", `-15m` for "15 minutes" ago.

For absolute times, "approximately RFC 3339 or ISO 8601" timestamps in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format are accepted (as well as just the date part or the time part), e.g. `16:30` for 4:30pm.